# multiple file upload fields within same model

Tags: django, django-views

I have a 'ProjectRecord' model with several filefields:

```
class ProjectRecord(models.Model):
prjname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
agencyID = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
...
upload_template1 = models.FileField(max_length=100, upload_to="media/%Y%m%d", blank=True, null=True)
    upload_template2 = models.FileField(max_length=100, upload_to="media/%Y%m%d", blank=True, null=True)
    upload_template3 = models.FileField(max_length=100, upload_to="media/%Y%m%d", blank=True, null=True)
```

my upload handler is very basic:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file): 
     destination = open('tmp.pdf', 'wb+') 
     for chunk in file.chunks(): 
             destination.write(chunk) 
             destination.close()
```

and my view function is as follows:

```
def edit_project(request, agencyID):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            a=ProjectRecord.objects.get(agencyID=agencyID)
            form = RecordForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=a)
            if form.is_valid():
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['upload_template1', 'upload_template2', 'upload_template3' ])
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('login.html')
    else:
            a=ProjectRecord.objects.get(agencyID=agencyID)
            form = RecordForm(instance=a)
    return render_to_response('portalproduction/production.html', {'form': form})
```

the existing code works only so long as I have a single file request:

```
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['upload_template1'])
```

as soon as I add multiple file requests (like the former view function), I get key errors.
Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible, and can someone help me with the view function?

this is a condesed version of the generated source

```
<div id="formshell" class="clearfix">
<form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div id="" class="component_stage clearfix">

        <div class="component_wrapper edit cw1">
            <table>
                <tr><td><input id="id_sellnumber1" type="text" name="sellnumber1" value="01" maxlength="30" /></td><td><input id="id_format1" type="text" name="format1" value="Inline Brochure" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input id="id_componentname1" type="text" name="componentname1" value="PA-to-SC_Redhead Brochure" maxlength="200" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="upload_template1" id="id_upload_template1" /></td></tr>
            </table>

        </div> 
        <div class="component_wrapper edit cw2">
            <table>
                <tr><td><input id="id_sellnumber2" type="text" name="sellnumber2" value="02" maxlength="30" /></td><td><input id="id_format2" type="text" name="format2" value="OE" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input id="id_componentname2" type="text" name="componentname2" value="PA-to-SC_RedheadOE" maxlength="200" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="upload_template2" id="id_upload_template2" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="component_wrapper edit cw3" style="margin-right:0;">
            <table>
                <tr><td><input id="id_sellnumber3" type="text" name="sellnumber3" maxlength="30" /></td><td><input id="id_format3" type="text" name="format3" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input id="id_componentname3" type="text" name="componentname3" maxlength="200" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="upload_template3" id="id_upload_template3" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>



    <div id=""><input type='file' name='file' id='file'/><input type="submit" value="save record" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data` in yout html template ? if not post the form code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.FILES` simply has no key: `('upload_template1', 'upload_template2', 'upload_template3')`

It's `request.FILES['upload_template1'], request.FILES['upload_template2'], request.FILES['upload_template3']`

```
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['upload_template1'])
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['upload_template2'])
#... so on.
```

This would illustrate your problem:

```
dic = {'key1':'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
print dic['key1', 'key2']
# KeyError

dic['key1', 'key2'] = 'value3'
print dic['key1', 'key2']
# out: value3
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. code produces MultiValueDictKeyError
Key 'upload_template2' not found in <MultiValueDict: {u'upload_template1': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>

Comment: Then you're not posting a second `<input type="file"` field with name `'upload_template2'`

Comment: yeah, it's there. the framework automatically generates the type=file as an attribute of the FileField and name= always uses the name of the field.

Comment: @kjarsenal is it inside the form tags? Can we see the HTML generated? That's bizarre if your browser is sending one file but not the other 2.

Comment: after further testing, it seems that the code DOES indeed work, but only so long as all of the upload fields have files attached. If I only upload one or two, then try to save the record, it throws the error. The form works as intended in the admin.

Comment: Nice! It's your responsibility to handle that case. Use dict.get(my key) to return None if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: I'll have to go back to the docs for syntax but thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: Get is a standard method on python dictionaries which request.FILES Implements. Try {}.get('doesntexist') -- it won't throw a key error